# $n$ solutions Sudoku

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Is there an algorithm which can calculate a $9 \times 9$ Sudoku with non-trivial $n$ possible solutions?

So if you play it you can play it for example 4 times? So if you play it there's a choice in which way you solve the Sudoku.

So, for example, we have a row in which it's possible to place two numbers in 2 ways for getting a valid result for the whole Sudoku that would mean you can play it 2 times.

My question is if there's a suitable method for "constructing" this kind of Sudokus?

Comment: please elaborate